# Basic Leaflet example not showing anything in the browser

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I am having trouble getting the basic LeafletJS example working. My logs indicate that LeafletJS is being imported and something is being bound to my #map div. Also the network tab in my debugger confirms that the leaflet.js and leaflet.css are being loaded.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? All I am seeing is a blank white browser window.

Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
        #map{ height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        console.log('L', L)

        const position = [51.505, -0.09];
        const map = L.map('map').setView(position, 13);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        console.log('map', map)
    </script>
</body
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not in leaflet code, but rather in css. You specified `#map` div's height to be `100%`, but its parent's height (`<body>`) is not set. Additionally, you need to set the width of `#map` as well.

Refer to this slightly modified jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k16r8s9g/